# How to run the whole content of my div in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm having trouble appending the content of my div using for loop. A new div is created under the code, however, the following are not included in the loop:

```html
<div class="row">

//not included in loop
        <div class="col-md-2 hour time-block" value="9:00">
          <p>9:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 textarea"></div>
        <button class="col-md-2 saveBtn">Save</button>
//not included in loop

      </div>
```

This is my current code:
HTML

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = "hour" + i;
  newDiv.className = "row";
  $(".container").append(newDiv);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Timeblocks go here -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hour time-block" value="9:00">
      <p>9:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 textarea"></div>
    <button class="col-md-2 saveBtn">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly are you trying to do, and what doesn't work? Are there any error messages? Do you know approximately where it goes wrong?

Comment: Your code is working, you're just not assigning any content inside the divs you're creating so you won't be able to see anything. Add `newDiv.textContent = i;` to it adds the value of `i` to your div as text to see each div

Answer (score 1):

You're in a right direction. As your div is missing the text part for for a visual ( display in UI) that's why its not appearing.

Take a look of the below code.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
 // This is jQuery way of appending the div. if you want to reuse your code add this line newDiv.textContent = i;
  let p = $('<p/>').text('para ' + i); // This is missing. Add this to display.
  let div = $('<div/>').addClass('row').attr("id", "hour" + i);
  div.append(p);
  $(".container").append(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hour time-block" value="9:00">
      <p>9:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 textarea"></div>
    <button class="col-md-2 saveBtn">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, thanks for the help! However, I am trying to run these other divs and the button under <div class="row">

Comment: you can use `after` instead of `append` to append after the div.

Comment: if you'll inspect the elements then you'll come to know all these are appended after the row.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an array of Elements , Which can be pushed in to the array, And render through **.html()** function
[Working JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/17xmfdoc/2/)

Your js should be

```
let list = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

 list.push(`<div id="hour${i}" class="row">Your ${i} Row </div>`); 

}

$(".container").html(list);
```

Note **** **Make your code as simple as possible.**